# Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, query, aggregate

I'm trying to order an aggregated query by a date field and Salesforce is giving me conflicting errors.

In the below code I have `max(Last_Referral_Date__c)` with an `order by Last_Referral_Date__c`. Using the query below I get:

> Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated

If I add Last_Referral_Date__c to the group by section I get:

> Aggregated field can not be grouped by error.

```
 String sQuery = 'Select Referral_Partner__r.ID referralID, count(ID) numOfReferral,';
        sQuery += ' max(Account__r.Projected_Annual_Revenue__c) Billing,';
        sQuery += ' max(Last_Referral_Date__c) lastReferralDate from Referrals__c';
        sQuery += ' Group By Referral_Partner__r.ID   Having max(Last_Referral_Date__c) <Last_N_DAYS : 90';
        sQuery += ' Order by Last_Referral_Date__c ASC';

        List<AggregateResult> Referrals = Database.query(sQuery);
        for (AggregateResult ar :Referrals) {

            System.Debug('Date: ' + ar.get('Last_Referral_Date__c'));
        }
```

I need to be able to order by the `Last_Referral_Date__c` field but am not sure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not grouping by that field, you can only order by an aggregation of that field. For example you can use `ORDER BY MAX(DateField__c)` but not `ORDER BY DateField__c`.